# PHP: problems with charset

Tags: html

In my php result page letter ä, ü, ö, ß displayed with a "?"
Fill `&uuml;` and so on works, but is there a easier way to solve this problem?

I tried this tag, but it doesn´t work

````
<html lang="de">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">```
````

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<html lang="de">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
Wie geht's? Ich möchte etwas schreiben. Tschüss.
</body>
</html>
```

Remember to save the HTML file as UTF-8.

Comment: I have a new problem with charset utf-8. Now my paddings and margins from the css file doesn´t work. I set utf-8 via notepad in css and html files an add @charset "utf-8"; in top of css file

Comment: I don't have enough information to help you with this. You could ask a new question, but please first read: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)